# Buliding user interface. Errors in string.xml that I cannot resolve

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is the string.xml. I am getting an errors although I cannot see an error.  Any advice? Specifically the errors are on the app name and settings lines.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Broken</string>
        <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
        <string name="button_send">send</string>
        <string name="action_settings">settings</string>
        <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    </resources>
```

This is the error message.
[2014-04-14 13:15:24 - Broken] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2014-04-14 13:18:47 - Broken] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: are you sure the problem is within this file?

Comment: clean and build the project, clearly suggesting that aborting build.
waiting for reply

Comment: It must be a different file.  Copy pasting the contents of this snippet into any android application's `strings.xml` does not raise any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it sends this error if you are using a string reference that no longer exist int the Strings.xml file.. Try and search throu all your layout files and menus to see if every String reference exists

Comment: will you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `clean and build` the project. Your error will go by doing that.